# Multikey `table/sortrows` using custom sort orders

Tags: matlab, sorting

How can I sort the rows of table using custom (i.e. non-standard) sort orders for some of the sort columns?

For example, the display below shows the output of `sortrows`, featuring standard sort orders for all the sort columns:

```
>> sortrows(A, {'TrafficLight', 'Suit', 'Parity'})
ans = 
    Parity    TrafficLight      Suit      order    prevalence
    ______    ____________    ________    _____    __________
    even      'green'         hearts      49       0.5025    
    even      'green'         hearts      64       0.5318    
    even      'green'         hearts      67       0.7896    
    odd       'green'         hearts       4       0.6374    
    odd       'green'         hearts      11       0.3354    
    odd       'green'         hearts      59       0.8644    
    even      'green'         spades      35       0.6674    
    odd       'green'         spades      64       0.4348    
    even      'red'           diamonds    69       0.5751    
    even      'red'           diamonds    77       0.6318    
    even      'red'           diamonds    89       0.2629    
    even      'red'           diamonds    92       0.2596    
    even      'red'           diamonds    98       0.3578    
    odd       'red'           diamonds    69       0.2911    
    odd       'red'           diamonds    74       0.3343    
    even      'red'           hearts      19       0.5695    
    odd       'red'           hearts      51       0.9122    
    even      'red'           spades      38       0.9837    
    odd       'red'           spades      22       0.5587    
    even      'yellow'        clubs       22       0.6917    
    odd       'yellow'        diamonds     1       0.2064    
    odd       'yellow'        diamonds    25       0.8257    
    odd       'yellow'        spades      33       0.2653    
    odd       'yellow'        spades      38       0.2549
```

But let's suppose that I want the sort order for the `TrafficLight` values to be

```
'red' < 'yellow' < 'green'
```

the one for the `Suit` values to be

```
diamonds < hearts < clubs < spades
```

and the one for the `Parity` to stay as it is.

> How can I re-order the rows of `A` such that the new ordering reflects these custom sort orders?

(Of course, the re-ordering of the rows must respect the sort key precedence specified in the original call to `sortrows`, namely `'TrafficLight' < 'Suit' < 'Parity'`.)

---

PS: Code to generate `A`:

```
kvs = {'Parity', 'TrafficLight', 'Suit'};
A = cell2table({
                'odd', 'yellow', 'diamonds', 1, 0.2064;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 4, 0.6374;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 11, 0.3354;
                'even', 'red', 'hearts', 19, 0.5695;
                'even', 'yellow', 'clubs', 22, 0.6917;
                'odd', 'red', 'spades', 22, 0.5587;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'diamonds', 25, 0.8257;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'spades', 33, 0.2653;
                'even', 'green', 'spades', 35, 0.6674;
                'even', 'red', 'spades', 38, 0.9837;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'spades', 38, 0.2549;
                'even', 'green', 'hearts', 49, 0.5025;
                'odd', 'red', 'hearts', 51, 0.9122;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 59, 0.8644;
                'even', 'green', 'hearts', 64, 0.5318;
                'odd', 'green', 'spades', 64, 0.4348;
                'even', 'green', 'hearts', 67, 0.7896;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 69, 0.5751;
                'odd', 'red', 'diamonds', 69, 0.2911;
                'odd', 'red', 'diamonds', 74, 0.3343;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 77, 0.6318;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 89, 0.2629;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 92, 0.2596;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 98, 0.3578
               }, 'VariableNames', ...
               [kvs {'order', 'prevalence'}]);
A.Parity = categorical(A.Parity);
A.Suit = categorical(A.Suit);
```

Comment: +1 For well-presented question and for code to generate data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also answering for cells, for the same reason as Daniel.

My approach:

1. Define the order for each key.
2. Replace strings by their order index. You can do that very easily using the second output of `ismember`
3. Sort the array of replaced strings using the desired sort key precedence. Store the second output of `sort`, which tells the reordering of rows corresponding to the sorting.
4. Apply that reordering to the rows of the original array .

   ```
   parityOrder = {'even','odd'}; %// step 1
   colorOrder = {'red','yellow','green'};
   suitOrder = {'diamonds','hearts','clubs','spades'};

   [~, p] = ismember(A(:,1),parityOrder); %// step 2
   [~, c] = ismember(A(:,2),colorOrder);
   [~, s] = ismember(A(:,3),suitOrder);

   [~, ii] = sortrows([p c s],[2 3 1]); %// step 3

   result = A(ii,:); %// step 4
   ```

Comment: I did not know that facet of `ismember`.  Very useful.  Thanks!

Comment: @kjo Welcome! Yes, Matlab functions often have second or third outputs which turn out to be very useful

Answer (score 2):

I am answering this for Cells because my Matlab does not support tables.

```
%define an order:
colororder=@(x)(strcmp(x,'red')+strcmp(x,'yellow')*2+strcmp(x,'green')*3)
%get sorted indices
[~,ix]=sort(colororder(A(:,2)))
%sort:
A(ix,:)
```

Maybe you an apply this to tables as well. Would be a nice task for Enums, but Matlab does not support Enums.

Comment: Thanks!  I learned a lot from your answer.  I picked Luis Mendo's, though, because it's easier for me to see how to automate it.